# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathcal{S}\oplus S^\perp$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation, direct-sum

I was presented with this theorem: Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ can be uniquely written as the sum of some $x_1\in \mathcal{S}$ and $x_2 \in\mathcal{S}^\perp$ (where '$^\perp$' sign denotes orthogonal complement).

Proof presented: Let $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^k$ be a basis for $\mathcal{S}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Define
$$x_1 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k(x^Tv_i)v_i, \quad x_2 = x - x_1.$$
Then for each $1 \leq j \leq k$.
$$x_2^Tv_j = x^Tv_j-x_1^Tv_j = x^Tv_j-x^Tv_j = 0$$

**NOTE**: This was only labeled as a 'partial proof' as what is left to show is the uniqueness of the decomposition.

What I am confused about is how does this show that our $x$ was able to be decomposed. I am a bit lost. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: $x_1\in S$ and $x_2\in S^\perp$.

Comment: It is immediate from the definition of $x_1$ that it lies in $\mathcal{S}$, since it is a linear combination of vectors in $\mathcal{S}$. The calculation $x_2^T v_j = 0$ for all $j$ shows that $x_2 \in \mathcal{S}^\perp$, since if $x_2 \perp v_j$ then $x_2$ is orthogonal to any linear combination of the $v_j$.

Comment: You need $\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}$ to be an orthonormal basis for the proof to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the idea of the space being a direct sum is A:  Every element can be written as a sum of something in the first set and something in the second, and B:  that way of writing it is unique.

For A:   Note that since $v_i$ form a basis of $S$ and all of the $(x^Tv_i)$ are scalars,  the definition of $x_1$ has it as a linear combination of vectors in $S$ and therefore $x_1\in S$.   The second part shows that $x_2=x-x_1$ is in fact orthogonal to $x_1$,  and therefore $x_2\in S^{\perp}$.  This shows that there is A way of constructing something in $S$ and something in $S^\perp$ that add to $x$.

What is left is to assume you have another pair of elements,  $x_3\in S$,  $x_4\in S^\perp$  such that $x=x_3+x_4$ and then show that will force $x_3=x_1$ and $x_4=x_2$, which will show uniqueness

Comment: I see that makes sense! @Alan, where does the ability to go from $x^Tv_j-x_1^Tv_j \to x^Tv_j-x^Tv_j$ come from?

Comment: It comes from the fact that $x_1$ is defined on a basis,  so when you distribute the product across the sum all the terms $v_jv_i$ are orthogonal and hence 0 except when $j=i$  (Really the assumption should be that your basis is orthonormal)